# importing chai assertion from chai-openapi-response-validator plugin

Tags: cypress, chai

I am using Cypress.io framework, and I would like to implement chai plugin called **chai-openapi-response-validator** which contains a new assertion called satisfyApiSpec

https://github.com/openapi-library/OpenAPIValidators/tree/master/packages/chai-openapi-response-validator

I tried to install and add the plugin to the plugins/index.js file, but the assertion inside the cypress test is failing with an error: Invalid Chai property: satisfyApiSpec

Is there another way to add this plugin, so the cypress / chai will learn a new assertion?

Answer (score 1):

You can add it at the top of the spec, or in `cypress/support/index.js` for all specs.

`cypress/plugins` is for node plugins, but browser-side plugins can be imported directly into specs or support/index.js.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiResponseValidator = require('chai-openapi-response-validator').;
chai.use(chaiResponseValidator('path/to/openapi.yml'));
```

---

**Getting around the fs.read() problem for this chai plugin**

From [npm: chai-openapi-response-validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-openapi-response-validator)

> **Loading your OpenAPI spec (3 different ways):**
>
> 2. From an object:
>
> ```js
> // Load that OpenAPI object into this plugin
> chai.use(chaiResponseValidator(openApiSpec));
> ```

so you can require the object before initializing the plugin

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiResponseValidator = require('chai-openapi-response-validator');
const openApiSpec = require('path/to/openapi.yml');
chai.use(chaiResponseValidator(openApiSpec));
```

---

An alternative - take a look at [cy-spok](https://github.com/bahmutov/cy-spok) to validate the API response.

The [linked video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MLDsqBd_gVU) shows in action with an intercept.

Comment: Thanks, looks like it loaded, because I have a new error with fs.read

  > Object.setPrototypeOf: expected an object or null, got undefined


node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:139:1


 // This ensures `util.promisify` works as it does for native `fs.read`.
if (Object.setPrototypeOf) Object.setPrototypeOf(read, fs$read)
return read
})(fs.read)

Comment: Ok, looks like I was wrong for this particular chai plugin. It uses `fs.read` which is only available in nodejs (not the browser). Need to check if there's a different way to call `chai.use(chaiResponseValidator)` by requiring `openapi.yml` and passing in the file contents.

Comment: Another note - take a look at [cy-spok](https://github.com/bahmutov/cy-spok) as an alternate way of validating the API response.